# How to accurately calculate number of samples in .wav file in javascript or c#

Tags: javascript, c#, audio

I'm trying to calculate the number of samples in a wave file. I use the formula:

```
Subchunk2Size    = NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
```

Using the formula above, I get  a different values than what's reported in Audacity and other standard Wave Editors. I scanned the headers for all the required information, but the formula only works for some files.

Audio files: [audio file 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oVvC_gqpUCkT7VnZp2WyJ-qbXECK18Sh/view?usp=sharing)
[Audio File 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WvKsOzV3O5K_ChdwtQqCdOY5tdOwAErJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Based on the little information you provide to go on, there is also a "BitsPerSample" in the WAV header - so you might not want to set that fixed to 8

Comment: NumSamples ,NumChannels  & BitsPerSample are not fixed values. Those values are detected from the file header. I have attached two audio files as an example

Comment: Just like I said; don't divide by 8 as a default, besides that subchunk2size should also be available in the header